# swift 2 get integer value from unwrap variable

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
let g : String? = self.EKOMemberShipss[0].SUB_TYP_Price

          let x:Int? = Int(g!)

         self.valuePla.text = "\(x)"
```

### Result

g   String? "   Optional(50)"

x   Int?      nil   None

---

I just want to get x = 50

[image]

Comment: I shouldn't convert to int and then back to string, this dos the same: `let g : String? = self.EKOMemberShipss[0].SUB_TYP_Price      
         self.valuePla.text = g!`

Comment: I just want to get 50 in string or int doesn't matter self.valuePla.text = "\(g)" give me optional(50)

Comment: maybe it helps if you don't convert it twice but just as I typed above

Comment: yeah i did it with "!" and without but same optional(50)

Comment: more than that i write    let g : String?  = self.EKOMemberShipss[0].SUB_TYP_Price
                
                let k = g!    and the result still g String? "Optional(50)" Some
k String "Optional(50)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104901/discussion-between-mommh-and-eric).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check both the `SUB_TYP_Price` and the ability to be converted to `Int`

On success the optional is unwrapped respectively

```
if let g = self.EKOMemberShipss[0].SUB_TYP_Price, x = Int(g) {
      self.valuePla.text = "\(x)"
}
```

Edit: According the screenshot`SUB_TYP_Price` is already `String?` so the downcast is not needed.

Comment: the if condition false , but how to check SUB_TYP_Price is able to be converted to int ?

Comment: The code does that actually: If `SUB_TYP_Price` is available (g), convert it to `Int` (x). If both expressions succeed set the label.

Comment: i don't no but the "if" false can't  convert x to int , more than that i write `let g : String? = self.EKOMemberShipss[0].SUB_TYP_Price let k = g!` ** and the result still g String? "Optional(50)" Some k String "Optional(50)" **

Comment: If `SUB_TYP_Price` is not available nothing happens otherwise g gets unwrapped, the exclamation mark is not needed. And don't use that type annotations, the compiler will tell you if a type couldn't be inferred.

Comment: i add photo to the question it describe the problem

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

Comment: This error indicates that the argument – right from the equal sign – is a non-optional.

Comment: i am sorry for ur time but it give me now Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[EKOMemberShips]'

Comment: Ok, forget that, but something in the chain is an additional optional, otherwise my code is supposed to work

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like this and it should work. (of course change the let g to whatever you want, this is just an example)

```
  let g:String? = Optional("50")
print(g) //returns "Optional(50)"
let c = g!
print(c) //returns "50"
```

Comment: `let g:String? = self.EKOMemberShipss[0].SUB_TYP_Price
                print(g) //returns "Optional(50)"
                let c = g!
                print(c)`   the result    **g String? "Optional(50)" Some
c String "Optional(50)" **